# C# snippet needed to replicate VBA Like operator

Tags: c#, regex, vba

I am converting VBA code that contains the LIKE operator, as in

```
    dim sToken as String
    if sToken Like "(*,*)" then ...
```

In all cases the patterns use only the  *  wildcard which matches any string (including the empty string).  The VBA Like operator yields only a true/false result so it's up to the subsequent VBA code to parse further and pluck out the matching substrings whenever there's a match.

I'd be most appreciative if someone can provide a C# snippet to test for the same type of simple wildcard match.  If the snippet also yields matching substrings - even better.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, that particular pattern could be matched with

```
if (sToken.StartsWith("(") && sToken.EndsWith(")")
    && sToken.Contains(","))
```

but in general you *may* find it makes more sense to use regular expressions. For example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"^\(.*,.*\)$");

        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("x(a,b)")); // False due to the x
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(a,b)x")); // False due to the x
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(ab)"));   // False due to the lack of ,
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(a,b"));   // False due to the lack of )
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(a,b)"));   // True!
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(aaa,bbb)"));   // True!
        Console.WriteLine(regex.IsMatch("(,)"));   // True!
    }
}
```

Things to note with the pattern here:

- I've used a *verbatim string literal* (the @ at the start) to make it easier to perform escaping *within* the regex
- ^ and $ force it to match the *whole* string
- The brackets are escaped so they're not treated as grouping operators

The MSDN ["Regular Expression Language Elements"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) page is a good reference for .NET regexes.

Answer (score 10):

Several people have suggested regular expressions which should work well for this scenario.  Another option is to use the VB `Like` operator directly from C# code.  This can be done by invoking the Compiler helper `LikeOperator.LikeString`.  This function is located in the VB runtime assembly, Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, and is usable from C#.

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;

...

if (LikeOperator.LikeString(sToken, "(*,*)")) { 
  ...
}
```

I don't believe this version has 100% parity with the VBA version of `Like` but it will be extremely close and will match for the common scenarios.

Comment: If your legacy app received like operator filtering from the users and you still want to support the same syntax for backwards-compatibility of users then this is the way to go. Otherwise use RegEx for new code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some stellar matching power, I suggest getting into [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html).